# Get nested value in JSONB column POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `guest_group` with a jsonb column. I want to query one ID where the `ID_Context` is equal to `protelIO`.

Here the column of the table:

```
[
   {
      "protelSurname":"Smith",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "protel-info"
      ],
      "protelUniqueID":"[{\"ID\":\"294623726\",\"Type\":\"21\",\"ID_Context\":\"GHA\"},{\"ID\":\"4842148\",\"Type\":\"1\",\"ID_Context\":\"protelIO\"}]",
      "protelGivenName":"Seth"
   },
   {
      "value":"test",
      "display_name":"Traces",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "trace"
      ]
   }
]
```

My try:

```
SELECT field ->>'protelUniqueID' 
FROM guest_group gg  cross join lateral  
jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field  
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
```

This gave me:

`[{"ID":"294623726","Type":"21","ID_Context":"GHA"},{"ID":"4842148","Type":"1","ID_Context":"protelIO"}]`

How can I go the last mile an only get the value of the `ID` key with the value key pair `"ID_Context":"protelIO"`?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the desired result I think.  Not very pretty perhaps :-)

```
select * from (select jsonb_array_elements(f) from (
    select (field ->>'protelUniqueID')::jsonb f
    FROM guest_group gg,
    lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
    WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
) d(f)) dd(x) 
where x->>'ID_Context'='protelIO';
```